# What is the Angular jqlite equivalent or solution for $( new Image() )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I have created a factory to pre-load images. Somewhere in this factory I use:

```
var image = $( new Image() )
                    .load(
                        function( event ) {
                            // Do Stuff
                        }
                    )
                    .error(
                        function( event ) {
                            // Do Stuff
                            );
                        }
                    )
```

This code was working. But I am working on removing the jQuery lib from my project and rely solely on using Angular's build-in jqlite.

I tried to find the solution by myself, but i just can't figure it out. I need the .load and .error function events to properly catch pre-load states.
This is a factory, so I do not want to create DOM elements here.

Does anyone has an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need jQuery here at all. Equivalent code in vanila JS would be:

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function (event) {
    // Do Stuff
};

image.onerror = function (event) {
    // Do Stuff
};

image.src = src;
```

Comment: I feel so incredibly stupid right now. Been focusing on the jqlite solution so blindly, I totally missed looking at a vanilla JS solution. Thank you for saving me from total blindness ;)

Comment: No, problem, glad it was useful.